# Moving values in a column to a specific row

Tags: r, rows

I have dataset in my bachelor thesis.
This is just a short version of the dataset (still too much to post it here, sorry),
but the case is, I have to make a list for each year with `Return12` for `year` 9 compared to the `SROE`-value for `year` 8, `Return12` year 10 with `SROE` for `year` 9, etc.
The company `ID` is in the second column and have to match the `SROE` and `Return12`, so the companies dont get mixed up.

I have tried with some different functions, but it does not solve my case.

I have tried this code, but it does not work like i want it to.

```r
year.order2 <- ret12[order(ret12$year, ret12$SROE, ret12$Return12, na.last = T, decreasing = T),]
yeartest <- transform(year.order2, Return12 = c(NA, Return12[-nrow(year.order2)]))
```

```
             id year         SROE     Return12  OSEBXr12
1814        166   15  21.06345172 -0.160281717 -0.059150
582          53   15  13.32248824  0.101805502 -0.059150
868          79   15   9.45765120  0.916125271 -0.059150
395          36   15   8.91144364 -0.046316276 -0.059150
318          29   15   6.87606276 -0.177370031 -0.059150
1286        118   15   6.75801735  1.069037413 -0.059150
329          30   15   6.44705341  0.398571429 -0.059150
1319        121   15   6.40374891  0.617598303 -0.059150
956          88   15   6.38674853  1.382978723 -0.059150
373          34   15   6.24516436 -0.057201646 -0.059150
1154        106   15   5.94762885  0.289787481 -0.059150
626          57   15   5.13702836  0.110565500 -0.059150
1539        141   15   5.06195259 -0.235493373 -0.059150
1704        156   15   4.96444477  0.381119862 -0.059150
967          89   15   4.49788681 -0.168720150 -0.059150
1451        133   15   4.16517045  0.291875733 -0.059150
1803        165   15   3.84209438  0.258043950 -0.059150
197          18   15   3.79648512 -0.111447964 -0.059150
1528        140   15   3.55027135  0.426369168 -0.059150
1737        159   15   3.43669721  0.413409961 -0.059150
241          22   15   3.12265152 -0.677819083 -0.059150
54            5   15   2.99865083  0.594527262 -0.059150
1660        152   15   2.98208332 -0.116092772 -0.059150
1693        155   15   2.72894105  0.315186197 -0.059150
1055         97   15   2.59080259 -0.288888889 -0.059150
1011         93   15   2.52560311 -0.245794393 -0.059150
989          91   15   2.37809304  0.006064505 -0.059150
450          41   15   2.34690356  0.012987013 -0.059150
1770        162   15   2.32962182 -0.223670187 -0.059150
802          73   15   2.28667081  0.120406075 -0.059150
1462        134   15   2.24283341 -0.028824886 -0.059150
549          50   15   2.15182069 -0.468315301 -0.059150
285          26   15   2.08732229 -0.271859964 -0.059150
10            1   15   1.97156443  0.482100054 -0.059150
340          31   15   1.93518075  0.899027442 -0.059150
1176        108   15   1.92194207 -0.139118199 -0.059150
1066         98   15   1.84783091  0.389512481 -0.059150
1748        160   15   1.83224060 -0.043163852 -0.059150
1781        163   15   1.80810900 -0.130968785 -0.059150
1407        129   15   1.76854453  0.548725101 -0.059150
208          19   15   1.71286374  0.280728627 -0.059150
824          75   15   1.60228776  0.279648956 -0.059150
1132        104   15   1.55899607  0.768918919 -0.059150
703          64   15   1.53559636 -0.772245890 -0.059150
43            4   15   1.53499544  0.692307692 -0.059150
1352        124   15   1.51347913 -0.537500000 -0.059150
1198        110   15   1.49695624  0.277698086 -0.059150
120          11   15   1.44169619  1.032124757 -0.059150
1550        142   15   1.43922411 -0.075267137 -0.059150
406          37   15   1.43645465 -0.661764706 -0.059150
263          24   15   1.40896986 -0.440000000 -0.059150
1297        119   15   1.39968959  0.005263158 -0.059150
1363        125   15   1.37839665 -0.206253758 -0.059150
857          78   15   1.36001779  0.223417484 -0.059150
109          10   15   1.32579947 -0.289615397 -0.059150
186          17   15   1.31100145  0.184308881 -0.059150
912          84   15   1.30878950 -0.259685157 -0.059150
472          43   15   1.30834391 -0.153648794 -0.059150
659          60   15   1.30399083  0.112676367 -0.059150
1671        153   15   1.29325084 -0.270092033 -0.059150
1825        167   15   1.23598258  0.128611436 -0.059150
1594        146   15   1.22400548  0.497863248 -0.059150
758          69   15   1.21047789  0.287523953 -0.059150
1440        132   15   1.20156226  0.011987913 -0.059150
835          76   15   1.18580289  0.840000000 -0.059150
846          77   15   1.17520829 -0.459869848 -0.059150
1682        154   15   1.16911115 -0.532894737 -0.059150
615          56   15   1.16624567  0.047679182 -0.059150
1506        138   15   1.16262451 -0.587982833 -0.059150
813          74   15   1.15630435 -0.142465321 -0.059150
560          51   15   1.14421086 -0.342842083 -0.059150
681          62   15   1.14286094  0.086538462 -0.059150
1616        148   15   1.13999073  0.680258790 -0.059150
1077         99   15   1.11327454 -0.136842105 -0.059150
142          13   15   1.10908331 -0.143200645 -0.059150
274          25   15   1.09553083 -0.313725490 -0.059150
1330        122   15   1.04979784  0.033805889 -0.059150
362          33   15   1.04725763 -0.132558140 -0.059150
1209        111   15   1.02722876 -0.548148148 -0.059150
692          63   15   1.02647920  0.725768322 -0.059150
175          16   15   0.99187168 -0.396054628 -0.059150
1429        131   15   0.98206425  0.233683616 -0.059150
1605        147   15   0.97786358 -0.213469388 -0.059150
890          82   15   0.97771373 -0.653846154 -0.059150
1231        113   15   0.97322215 -0.511597374 -0.059150
780          71   15   0.95005051  1.476789384 -0.059150
1165        107   15   0.94223541 -0.295668550 -0.059150
1033         95   15   0.93440462 -0.353345780 -0.059150
1572        144   15   0.93264693 -0.029200673 -0.059150
1374        126   15   0.92729234 -0.635913313 -0.059150
1495        137   15   0.91475915  0.399845573 -0.059150
648          59   15   0.86536731 -0.742239807 -0.059150
1044         96   15   0.86369475 -0.691011236 -0.059150
1792        164   15   0.86246004 -0.429643121 -0.059150
714          65   15   0.85465118 -0.725639927 -0.059150
1484        136   15   0.84167952 -0.067357513 -0.059150
604          55   15   0.82344486  0.050573980 -0.059150
593          54   15   0.81699442 -0.054545455 -0.059150
527          48   15   0.81574188 -0.541223969 -0.059150
1308        120   15   0.78682497  0.090975610 -0.059150
164          15   15   0.75097824  0.113962960 -0.059150
1121        103   15   0.73844731  2.831560758 -0.059150
1649        151   15   0.72396064 -0.835227273 -0.059150
571          52   15   0.71393614 -0.670806343 -0.059150
153          14   15   0.71010885  0.199908967 -0.059150
637          58   15   0.70854122 -0.896969697 -0.059150
945          87   15   0.70774797  1.402923537 -0.059150
1473        135   15   0.70710688 -0.828676471 -0.059150
1110        102   15   0.69097013 -0.168269231 -0.059150
1396        128   15   0.68369318  0.250000000 -0.059150
1253        115   15   0.67988410 -0.365682093 -0.059150
1759        161   15   0.67049105 -0.367088608 -0.059150
65            6   15   0.66389168 -0.540526316 -0.059150
219          20   15   0.64685798 -0.721890547 -0.059150
252          23   15   0.62984681 -0.463291139 -0.059150
1726        158   15   0.61402854 -0.436956522 -0.059150
1418        130   15  -0.79965248 -0.478260870 -0.059150
1549        142   14  23.11684369 -0.178885860  0.112869
317          29   14  20.23086241  0.644505325  0.112869
1318        121   14   8.58091313  1.007734881  0.112869
988          91   14   7.90873362 -0.269991974  0.112869
867          79   14   6.44919884  0.275177305  0.112869
328          30   14   6.40544835 -0.059629331  0.112869
1175        108   14   6.32482120  0.540399113  0.112869
1351        124   14   5.50407132  0.000000000  0.112869
1538        141   14   5.46883066 -0.179431025  0.112869
581          53   14   5.14092813  0.250627538  0.112869
1527        140   14   4.68597924 -0.071334648  0.112869
790          72   14   4.27448237  0.044596913  0.112869
240          22   14   3.72618752 -0.489240506  0.112869
1307        120   14   3.65873267 -0.125047671  0.112869
1505        138   14   3.62463735 -0.107279693  0.112869
9             1   14   3.60998039  0.042533569  0.112869
1285        118   14   3.59967078 -0.431940200  0.112869
196          18   14   3.56824369  0.612544044  0.112869
1692        155   14   3.37111155  0.194139194  0.112869
339          31   14   3.07045337  0.698513384  0.112869
1747        160   14   3.00051614  0.290793547  0.112869
1670        153   14   2.99930554  0.157513854  0.112869
801          73   14   2.98911215  0.056882806  0.112869
1593        146   14   2.97564257 -0.372822300  0.112869
1659        152   14   2.87893104  0.340008624  0.112869
1373        126   14   2.65668093 -0.350949463  0.112869
1197        110   14   2.61785580  0.233531310  0.112869
1703        156   14   2.60464237  0.181673156  0.112869
1769        162   14   2.57249329 -0.213467753  0.112869
53            5   14   2.43112019  0.332925097  0.112869
1131        104   14   2.42196540  0.075172554  0.112869
1736        159   14   2.39665786  0.767601043  0.112869
636          58   14   2.31838774 -0.550000000  0.112869
284          26   14   2.17325240 -0.390076974  0.112869
262          24   14   2.15494774 -0.393939394  0.112869
1516        139   14   2.12650027 -0.437762869  0.112869
1010         93   14   2.00163574  0.789297659  0.112869
372          34   14   1.95460996  0.435506242  0.112869
548          50   14   1.95355193 -0.680153093  0.112869
1076         99   14   1.91838973  0.490926925  0.112869
1450        133   14   1.82737021  0.193544383  0.112869
460          42   14   1.78104084 -0.418705036  0.112869
1153        106   14   1.77902235  0.399846259  0.112869
1813        166   14   1.77211578  0.612540666  0.112869
185          17   14   1.76411747  0.363361388  0.112869
680          62   14   1.72407748 -0.460580913  0.112869
691          63   14   1.71478535 -0.364864865  0.112869
1494        137   14   1.69161571  0.106408757  0.112869
614          56   14   1.65779152  0.084792900  0.112869
1780        163   14   1.62571349 -0.230977814  0.112869
702          64   14   1.62480728 -0.512077295  0.112869
1208        111   14   1.59762131 -0.560260586  0.112869
592          54   14   1.59175502 -0.316087737  0.112869
735          67   14   1.44799035 -0.155844156  0.112869
273          25   14   1.43157370  0.280334728  0.112869
1406        129   14   1.42599186  0.694259743  0.112869
559          51   14   1.41919468 -0.374564480  0.112869
42            4   14   1.40889942  0.090621089  0.112869
97            9   14   1.40809834 -0.439447147  0.112869
207          19   14   1.40806506  0.306086405  0.112869
394          36   14   1.39957200  0.086343404  0.112869
405          37   14   1.39021190 -0.165848871  0.112869
526          48   14   1.35374016 -0.713503901  0.112869
163          15   14   1.34048347 -0.411522634  0.112869
1571        144   14   1.32108835 -0.082097870  0.112869
1725        158   14   1.31531715 -0.252032520  0.112869
625          57   14   1.31394786  0.171449830  0.112869
658          60   14   1.31200671 -0.240147697  0.112869
1054         97   14   1.31136914 -0.566265060  0.112869
1461        134   14   1.26710097 -0.410000000  0.112869
1065         98   14   1.26289838  0.747161593  0.112869
1758        161   14   1.26275618  0.519879889  0.112869
1164        107   14   1.23857503  0.234883721  0.112869
449          41   14   1.23381575  0.247141768  0.112869
823          75   14   1.23084920  0.505203218  0.112869
1043         96   14   1.19762524  0.311233886  0.112869
779          71   14   1.19489416 -0.061111111  0.112869
75            7   14   1.18112630 -0.057826087  0.112869
856          78   14   1.11758807  0.568019472  0.112869
416          38   14   1.10565310 -0.661290323  0.112869
944          87   14   1.08837331  1.441337890  0.112869
1296        119   14   1.03762698  0.478599222  0.112869
812          74   14   0.98145205 -0.151996606  0.112869
1604        147   14   0.97324462 -0.218089603  0.112869
570          52   14   0.91405742 -0.240557389  0.112869
966          89   14   0.90857225  0.015850587  0.112869
834          76   14   0.90626954  0.351351351  0.112869
603          55   14   0.90553614  0.120000000  0.112869
1681        154   14   0.90081211  0.032258065  0.112869
218          20   14   0.87615674 -0.359872611  0.112869
1483        136   14   0.87269220 -0.077086255  0.112869
1362        125   14   0.85469080 -0.389500734  0.112869
119          11   14   0.83707515  0.777252896  0.112869
911          84   14   0.82895276 -0.295532646  0.112869
1648        151   14   0.82599899 -0.200000000  0.112869
1252        115   14   0.82477468 -0.329849570  0.112869
1472        135   14   0.82033134  2.177570093  0.112869
1230        113   14   0.81397746 -0.556864986  0.112869
889          82   14   0.81389255 -0.428571429  0.112869
1439        132   14   0.77224072  0.378296306  0.112869
427          39   14   0.74909867 -0.315168827  0.112869
757          69   14   0.72448797  0.024644523  0.112869
152          14   14   0.70740409 -0.442857143  0.112869
1395        128   14   0.68401333 -0.118942731  0.112869
1186        109   14   0.66692557  0.205473743  0.112869
669          61   14   0.66651108 -0.411764706  0.112869
316          29   13  27.67796398  0.475557461  0.150159
1493        137   13  13.56200755  0.045216461  0.150159
1746        160   13  10.99968277  0.051940109  0.150159
1768        162   13   7.53413090  0.213153491  0.150159
239          22   13   6.95310312  0.046357616  0.150159
327          30   13   6.34254755  0.296625222  0.150159
1372        126   13   5.45573520  0.332028548  0.150159
1537        141   13   4.60641610  0.489180155  0.150159
789          72   13   4.34881818  2.761290323  0.150159
558          51   13   4.08086211 -0.043070363  0.150159
1306        120   13   4.07077399  0.099983769  0.150159
547          50   13   4.03234457 -0.061875401  0.150159
1702        156   13   3.95355025  0.181487296  0.150159
1548        142   13   3.89783966 -0.137992832  0.150159
8             1   13   3.80333107  0.220912940  0.150159
1174        108   13   3.77325183  0.147305733  0.150159
800          73   13   3.70624126  0.011274207  0.150159
1669        153   13   3.61855059 -0.172420877  0.150159
987          91   13   3.39669062  0.741665461  0.150159
690          63   13   3.39536421  4.414634146  0.150159
1735        159   13   3.19989358  0.082035101  0.150159
1185        109   13   2.84971719  1.499371647  0.150159
580          53   13   2.75702524  0.503066618  0.150159
1042         96   13   2.70983419  0.378172589  0.150159
1658        152   13   2.70327736  0.131344886  0.150159
195          18   13   2.69289531  0.042694820  0.150159
283          26   13   2.66181946 -0.081758086  0.150159
866          79   13   2.51063140  0.072275199  0.150159
1779        163   13   2.44508433  0.179777004  0.150159
613          56   13   2.43963461  0.013710104  0.150159
52            5   13   2.35899802  0.332536076  0.150159
1075         99   13   2.16278220  0.224624625  0.150159
1570        144   13   2.06554782  0.074010846  0.150159
525          48   13   2.03023407 -0.038518650  0.150159
1504        138   13   1.98459096  0.167515938  0.150159
1812        166   13   1.91311640 -0.066946965  0.150159
151          14   13   1.90382668  0.093750000  0.150159
338          31   13   1.84584193  0.091777983  0.150159
591          54   13   1.80853387  0.203619909  0.150159
272          25   13   1.78598713  1.728310502  0.150159
184          17   13   1.76112921  0.009867010  0.150159
1009         93   13   1.74752529  0.980132450  0.150159
1691        155   13   1.67190657 -0.197058824  0.150159
118          11   13   1.65524659  0.278160919  0.150159
437          40   13   1.61806035  0.014064277  0.150159
811          74   13   1.58880643 -0.153717037  0.150159
63            6   13   1.58381410 -0.165931982  0.150159
448          41   13   1.58348698 -0.090444673  0.150159
1592        146   13   1.57872558  0.332024277  0.150159
1724        158   13   1.55216473 -0.247964202  0.150159
1284        118   13   1.52735674 11.877689760  0.150159
1251        115   13   1.48634481 -0.318053446  0.150159
1130        104   13   1.46625297  2.543506189  0.150159
404          37   13   1.46229134  1.193756728  0.150159
1361        125   13   1.42651972  1.569811321  0.150159
1086        100   13   1.38033411 -0.930241731  0.150159
668          61   13   1.37085612  0.422074816  0.150159
569          52   13   1.34391491  0.158614113  0.150159
1438        132   13   1.34255306  0.693896980  0.150159
1317        121   13   1.34071609  0.732839506  0.150159
96            9   13   1.33847231 -0.259324009  0.150159
1614        148   13   1.31243851  0.120572362  0.150159
1603        147   13   1.30535127  0.085560151  0.150159
1229        113   13   1.25070855 -0.050632911  0.150159
1053         97   13   1.23077193 -0.135416667  0.150159
855          78   13   1.23018452  0.366298881  0.150159
217          20   13   1.22733648 -0.071005917  0.150159
1328        122   13   1.21687585 -0.146341463  0.150159
459          42   13   1.21666304 -0.379464286  0.150159
1163        107   13   1.21262434  0.137566138  0.150159
965          89   13   1.18173008  0.858823529  0.150159
206          19   13   1.16441222  0.208124942  0.150159
943          87   13   1.14644451 -0.767595508  0.150159
679          62   13   1.14255503  0.532591415  0.150159
1757        161   13   1.13108091 -0.477468616  0.150159
1647        151   13   1.12639353  1.244897959  0.150159
701          64   13   1.11588786 -0.577551020  0.150159
778          71   13   1.10966802 -0.090909091  0.150159
371          34   13   1.06990074  0.665256076  0.150159
1295        119   13   1.02445843 -0.284122563  0.150159
734          67   13   1.00937090 -0.478555305  0.150159
1449        133   13   0.99690576 -0.016393442  0.150159
261          24   13   0.99320149 -0.423580786  0.150159
1196        110   13   0.95969164  0.062824513  0.150159
1482        136   13   0.95074932  0.033018868  0.150159
822          75   13   0.92045109  0.259812898  0.150159
1526        140   13   0.91234577  0.362339810  0.150159
1207        111   13   0.90909480  0.100358423  0.150159
1405        129   13   0.90775970  0.475961538  0.150159
657          60   13   0.90306208  3.213508197  0.150159
602          55   13   0.86449560  0.999999999  0.150159
183          17   12  12.19940204  0.008113526  0.172201
1492        137   12   9.88702902  0.092625661  0.172201
194          18   12   8.51621898  0.228817367  0.172201
546          50   12   6.80902674  0.305842246  0.172201
1536        141   12   5.96245535  0.167890067  0.172201
326          30   12   5.95646725 -0.018736383  0.172201
1811        166   12   5.81124269  0.268209538  0.172201
1371        126   12   5.51770644  0.189542484  0.172201
392          36   12   4.50167386  0.269362552  0.172201
447          41   12   4.21790966 -0.091686379  0.172201
216          20   12   4.15954590 -0.417241379  0.172201
557          51   12   4.15186011  0.208791209  0.172201
799          73   12   3.65748981  0.149911331  0.172201
1547        142   12   3.38614688  0.861518705  0.172201
1569        144   12   3.14547059  0.034114646  0.172201
1503        138   12   3.08482928  0.108910891  0.172201
1173        108   12   2.98874897  0.144519795  0.172201
524          48   12   2.96726211 -0.106050749  0.172201
1668        153   12   2.82006942  0.445982767  0.172201
568          52   12   2.78044947  0.252641825  0.172201
1646        151   12   2.73729474  0.447373101  0.172201
1305        120   12   2.66133730  0.095990358  0.172201
51            5   12   2.62860138  0.453081557  0.172201
62            6   12   2.58973221  0.733007177  0.172201
1734        159   12   2.54991113  0.148192719  0.172201
986          91   12   2.50720858 -0.142857143  0.172201
1591        146   12   2.48325687 -0.034137931  0.172201
1745        160   12   2.47639237 -0.089179887  0.172201
612          56   12   2.46973545  0.172545127  0.172201
1657        152   12   2.45588097  0.324941037  0.172201
238          22   12   2.45041065 -0.460714286  0.172201
1008         93   12   2.38060628 -0.174863388  0.172201
304          28   12   2.38003456  0.366390417  0.172201
689          63   12   2.35868026 -0.250000000  0.172201
282          26   12   2.21960529  0.154440154  0.172201
579          53   12   2.20123380  0.352456021  0.172201
865          79   12   2.13139273  0.154602047  0.172201
40            4   12   2.08207931 -0.016197073  0.172201
964          89   12   2.07859137  0.053780182  0.172201
1767        162   12   1.97715726  0.626024053  0.172201
1294        119   12   1.85382604 -0.028205128  0.172201
1283        118   12   1.83548975  1.479564033  0.172201
656          60   12   1.79853322  0.837349397  0.172201
271          25   12   1.76021383 -0.354611726  0.172201
590          54   12   1.69943635 -0.059671471  0.172201
1701        156   12   1.68628544  0.106797253  0.172201
1690        155   12   1.65291529 -0.096632588  0.172201
7             1   12   1.65211344  0.140809487  0.172201
1074         99   12   1.64881940  1.134615385  0.172201
1327        122   12   1.57204072 -0.132275132  0.172201
1261        116   12   1.56805209 -0.303030303  0.172201
1041         96   12   1.54257211 -0.428985507  0.172201
667          61   12   1.51717722 -0.136690647  0.172201
810          74   12   1.50738969  0.341888698  0.172201
95            9   12   1.50651922 -0.041340782  0.172201
1778        163   12   1.48473960  0.302116311  0.172201
161          15   12   1.43426560  0.150862069  0.172201
700          64   12   1.43398480 -0.579232099  0.172201
1360        125   12   1.40030030 -0.735612579  0.172201
1184        109   12   1.32326647  0.180575205  0.172201
1316        121   12   1.30587844  0.250000000  0.172201
920          85   12   1.28268472  0.102362205  0.172201
1228        113   12   1.26764800 -0.159574468  0.172201
1712        157   12   1.23739802  0.329823748  0.172201
403          37   12   1.23470156  0.140577041  0.172201
205          19   12   1.22583617  0.270007622  0.172201
1756        161   12   1.22561713 -0.900392157  0.172201
150          14   12   1.12110726  0.015873016  0.172201
117          11   12   1.08773604  0.087500000  0.172201
1679        154   12   1.01730540  0.273743017  0.172201
1085        100   12   0.99614726 -0.166723569  0.172201
733          67   12   0.97046135 -0.439240506  0.172201
755          69   12   0.95406148 -0.279629630  0.172201
821          75   12   0.92934814  0.729949635  0.172201
854          78   12   0.92924014  0.717964824  0.172201
942          87   12   0.92652589 -0.818032787  0.172201
1129        104   12   0.91253834  0.007936508  0.172201
1602        147   12   0.90914950  0.281739130  0.172201
1404        129   12   0.90468701  0.625000000  0.172201
1030         95   12   0.89828972 -0.130977229  0.172201
73            7   12   0.88164808  0.494091309  0.172201
1107        102   12   0.87885010  0.020431646  0.172201
1437        132   12   0.87071649  0.336884800  0.172201
1052         97   12   0.86737375 -0.587002557  0.172201
777          71   12   0.83710890  0.119688299  0.172201
348          32   12   0.82375721 -0.643449133  0.172201
458          42   12   0.81877908 -0.321212121  0.172201
337          31   12   0.81128328 -0.149206441  0.172201
1063         98   12   0.79934806  1.473684210  0.172201
678          62   12   0.79695044 -0.140710383  0.172201
249          23   12   0.79493117  0.318363273  0.172201
1723        158   12   0.78859160  0.429162228  0.172201
370          34   12   0.78024017  0.066666667  0.172201
436          40   12   0.77619489  0.129891304  0.172201
601          55   12   0.77193287  1.220248668  0.172201
139          13   12  -3.32258505  1.585585585  0.172201
578          53   11  45.76543378  0.228037564 -0.076420
182          17   11  11.61880543  0.092649764 -0.076420
1491        137   11  11.10701743 -0.099834528 -0.076420
1667        153   11  10.52229111  0.116544776 -0.076420
1106        102   11   9.11660210 -0.163753237 -0.076420
985          91   11   6.73195560 -0.561824388 -0.076420
193          18   11   6.11699997  0.039019964 -0.076420
1535        141   11   6.06085500 -0.413730672 -0.076420
303          28   11   5.95462907 -0.139209467 -0.076420
50            5   11   5.63631194  0.148517965 -0.076420
325          30   11   4.70780092  0.348885348 -0.076420
963          89   11   3.42521562 -0.080424577 -0.076420
798          73   11   3.39272134 -0.051378752 -0.076420
1744        160   11   3.03847970 -0.091287843 -0.076420
61            6   11   2.96322084 -0.215844382 -0.076420
1733        159   11   2.87609409 -0.130428605 -0.076420
160          15   11   2.86881209 -0.292682927 -0.076420
94            9   11   2.54069565  2.162544170 -0.076420
545          50   11   2.50990774 -0.033396566 -0.076420
1689        155   11   2.34290938  0.311896826 -0.076420
1656        152   11   2.29133789  0.118316301 -0.076420
611          56   11   2.19636482 -0.335638698 -0.076420
589          54   11   2.19581833 -0.253275109 -0.076420
1590        146   11   2.16014050 -0.348423877 -0.076420
281          26   11   2.09792109 -0.213768116 -0.076420
1502        138   11   2.08817684  0.068783069 -0.076420
864          79   11   2.05294729 -0.062938980 -0.076420
248          23   11   2.05179688 -0.296842105 -0.076420
6             1   11   1.98610066 -0.365344741 -0.076420
1172        108   11   1.86819779 -0.097636799 -0.076420
116          11   11   1.82851695 -0.284436228 -0.076420
1810        166   11   1.75851688 -0.260376164 -0.076420
1568        144   11   1.74672801  0.097011298 -0.076420
204          19   11   1.68777151 -0.416080308 -0.076420
1645        151   11   1.68005446 -0.540000000 -0.076420
391          36   11   1.61064785 -0.184871744 -0.076420
446          41   11   1.52375216 -0.135309245 -0.076420
1700        156   11   1.52348562  0.155791335 -0.076420
1128        104   11   1.50795925 -0.045454545 -0.076420
1546        142   11   1.50634306  1.017021276 -0.076420
1051         97   11   1.46633126 -0.464692483 -0.076420
1304        120   11   1.46249821  0.043560606 -0.076420
1326        122   11   1.43587335  0.125000000 -0.076420
270          25   11   1.42570485 -0.281250000 -0.076420
1007         93   11   1.40832289 -0.170318258 -0.076420
820          75   11   1.35452065 -0.432659647 -0.076420
369          34   11   1.31666123 -0.375000000 -0.076420
1601        147   11   1.31193259  0.244933411 -0.076420
1403        129   11   1.29946491 -0.471343246 -0.076420
556          51   11   1.28903970 -0.213177517 -0.076420
853          78   11   1.27235228 -0.444786553 -0.076420
1755        161   11   1.26301155  0.853197674 -0.076420
237          22   11   1.25496888 -0.496402878 -0.076420
941          87   11   1.23050445 -0.227848101 -0.076420
1766        162   11   1.19046710 -0.155750557 -0.076420
567          52   11   1.18480736  0.004008746 -0.076420
1777        163   11   1.13617940 -0.100416011 -0.076420
655          60   11   1.11783748 -0.520271663 -0.076420
1227        113   11   1.11366867 -0.262745098 -0.076420
```

Comment: in [mcve] there is "minimal"...

Comment: Thank you. Changed the text

Comment: Minimal *data*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with fake data and two methods to achieve your goal. As I don't know how you want to 'compare' these values, I am just using a simple formula as an illustration.

```
# Generate data
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:10,3),
           year = rep(14:16,each=10),
           SROE = rnorm(30,10,4),
           Return12 = rnorm(30,0,2)
)

library(dplyr)
```

**Option 1**
This method uses a `left_join`, joining the measurement of this year with that of a previous year. To match data of the current year with the previous year, I first mutate the year of the second data.frame with +1. The x and y in the columns generated represend the left (x) and the right (y) data.frame in the join (ie. `left %>% left_join(right)`)

```
# join data previous year
df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% mutate(year = year+1),by=c('id','year')) %>%
  mutate(compare = Return12.x - SROE.y)
```

**Option 2**
This method uses the `dplyr::lag` function. As this method depends on sorting your data and getting info from the previous row, you must be 100% sure that every id has all the years of interest. If not, for example because of missing observation, you will have to deal with that, for example with the function `dplyr::complete`

```
# Order data and use lag function
df %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(compare = Return12 - lag(SROE))
```